# Wireless network not working on HP Pavilion DV2000

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hp, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I cannot connect to a wireless network using Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop.

I have an HP Pavilion DV2000 p/n RN088EA#UUW. 
When I run the `lspci` command it shows I am using a Broadcom BCM4311.

I ran the command `rfkill list`. I read that it would show me if there was a soft or a hard block stopping my computer from wireless working. It showed neither soft or hard blocked.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Broadcom STA Wireless driver. That driver bundle says that it contains every driver:

- *This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-,
  BCM43224-, BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based hardware.*

Still I get no wireless connections.

And I have made sure that the hardware key is turned on. I've even tried reinstaling both with the hardware button turned on and off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh sorry. I did a some command in terminal rfkill list or something like that. I read that it would show me if there was a soft or a hard block stopping my computer from wireless working.  It showed neither soft or hard blocked

Comment: the network is a router, but i am pretty sure that the entire wireless option is missing for some reason. when the driver bundle is not installed the top navigation bar menu shows me both wireless and wired connections, with wireless telling me that firmware is missing. i went from using XP on it, to installing Ubuntu 12.04 as the only OS. so i have not connected to anything wireless in Ubuntu before having these troubles. wired connection works fine